# Parse Json in razor view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to parse JSON. I am using below code to parse JSON

```
var sr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CanvasJsonData));
```

Here `CanvasJsonData` is of type `string` and contains the following JSON string:

```
{  
   "client":{  
      "instanceId":"_:GPAT_Connect:18:2;a:canvasapp",
      "targetOrigin":"https://gcpaexp--gcpdev3q1.cs13.my.salesforce.com",
      "instanceUrl":"https://gcpaexp--GCPDEV3Q1.cs13.my.salesforce.com",
      "oauthToken":"00DW0000008sVOh!AR8AQLlBiYZZ0iJHv6xBOMSppnBkO_g0Vlug2072sPQ.JkgtRNpQh7zF0Qym7oDOQn1c3qhAmRAJ6VWr55zdpCDYp1WD_EI4"
   }
}
```

Am I doing correctly to parse Json? I need to do this mvc razor view.

Now, my problem is I get `sr.client` as `undefined`.

```
 var sr = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CanvasJsonData));           
             Sfdc.canvas(function() {
                Sfdc.canvas.client.publish(sr.client, {
                name: 'mybox.sendVal', payload: { value : 'request created'} });
            }) () ;
```

Comment: I rewrite your JSON string because it was not valide. Retest with the correct JSON in your answer and check if you still get the error.

Comment: Is it correct way of parsing the JSON @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CanvasJsonData)); or@Html.Raw(Model.CanvasJsonData);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `CanvasJsonData` is a `string` (not an `object`), you need to use `JSON.parse` to parse the string to JSON.

Assuming you model property is

```
model.CanvasJsonData = "{\"client\":{\"instanceId\":\"_:GPAT_Connect:18:2;a:canvasapp\",\"targetOrigin\":\"https://gcpaexp ...... }"
```

Then in the script

```
var sr = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CanvasJsonData))); // returns Object {client: Object}
console.log(sr.client.instanceId); // returns '_:GPAT_Connect:18:2;a:canvasapp'
```

Alternatively, `CanvasJsonData` should be an object containing a property `client` which contains properties `instanceId`, `targetOrigin` etc